# What is the name of the molecule HCCO?

Tags: chemical-compounds

I have a very hard time finding information about $HCCO$. I don't even know what it's name is.

I'd like to know what its main features are, where it shows up and/or what it's used for?

Comment: This does not seem to be a physics question (except in the snark sense of calling chemistry an effective theory of physics). There is [a area 51 proposal for chemistry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4964/chemistry) making good progress.

Comment: @dmckee: I know, I'm commited.

Comment: There is a database here [http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/form-ser.html](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/form-ser.html), however it doesn't find $HCCO$ in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this Google book hit](http://books.google.com/books?id=vWgJvKMXwQ8C&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=hcco%20compound&source=bl&ots=0T71raMG2c&sig=BK3IFtrbviGzuaJYB3Y_OWG1DA0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7XAiT76fCMu4hAfJmbXSBA&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCA), I think it's called a **ketenyl radical**. Searching [ketenyl radical](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=ketenyl%20radical) seems to bring up hits with the same compound formula.

Incidentally, it wasn't *that* hard to find by searching *hcco compound*. Ninth hit, I think...